# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have a dependancy [webview_flutter_android](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/main/packages/webview_flutter/webview_flutter). It's [build.gradle file](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/2c0fc55ba93886bc4937a438b559eb997e6b677d/packages/webview_flutter/webview_flutter_android/android/build.gradle) contains

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
    } 


compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

and from [here](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#jdk-17-agp). JDK 17 required to run AGP 8.0. Where I'm confused is that from the `compileOptions` `JAVA 8` seems to be ok for this plugin. But the android docs says you have to use JDK 17 required to run AGP 8.0. The context of the issue I'm having when building a production release with *fastlane* I. get the following error:

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':webview_flutter_android:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :webview_flutter_android
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':webview_flutter_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':webview_flutter_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I'm have `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk` installed. What does `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` actually mean and does it mean I can run the plugin run with JAVA 8. Do I have to download JAVA 17 for application to build. Also the error says

> Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component
> compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a
> component compatible with Java 8
> In this case what is the consumer and what is the component..

Comment: I don't see a problem in using JDK 17 for running Gradle and the plugin. Java 17 can without problems compile Java 8 source code and generate Java 8 class files.